# Need to predict a delivery date based on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is the situation, the product may or may not go throught a manufacturing process. And I need to know when I can expect to deliver it.

The prediction is based on the 'base_date' as in the pseudocode bellow:

`if (where_process2 = 002):`

`df[delivery] = df[base_date].AddDays(if [where_process1]=001 and [days_process1]=0 then 2 else [days_process1])`

`elif (where_process1 = 002):`

`df[delivery] = df[base_date].AddDays(if [where_process1]=001 and [days_process1]=0 then 2 else [days_process1])`

But the thing is, I have 160 diferent processes and need to calculate the forecast based on all where the "[where_process *N*]" has something on it, starting from the last process where the location is site 002.

**Is there a way to do this other than chaining 160 ifs inside of one another?**

DataSample
NS = Means it has to go throught the process, but hasn't yet.

| order | base_date | where_process1 | process1 | days_process1 | where_process2 | process2 | days_process2 | delivery |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 01.11.2021 | 001 | 06.11.2021 | 6 | 001 | 08.11.2021 | 2 | 10.11.2021 |
| 1235 | 01.11.2021 | 001 | 06.11.2021 | 6 |  |  |  | 06.11.2021 |
| 1236 | 01.11.2021 | 001 | 05.11.2021 | 5 | 001 | 05.11.2021 | 0 | 05.11.2021 |
| 1237 | 01.11.2021 | 001 | 05.11.2021 | 5 | 002 | 12.11.2021 | 7 | 12.11.2021 |
| 1238 | 01.11.2021 | 001 | 06.11.2021 | 6 | 001 | NS | 0 | 08.11.2021 |
| 1239 | 01.11.2021 | 001 | 08.11.2021 | 8 | 002 | NS | 0 | 10.11.2021 |

Comment: I'd start looking for a pattern that's common in all the if's you'd have to do and then run a loop using that pattern and probably a function to go with it. First pattern I'd see is all your processes have the same name and just a number that ends i.e. you can use f strings to access them iteratively df[f'where_process{i}'] and just loop through them, if that's not the case I'd create a dict or list with all the processes you need to iterate through.

Comment: I tried to do so by summing up every [days_process*N*] but I need to figure when it is going to arrive at site 002, and there are processes happening after that don't matter to me. I guess I need to loop throught the row in order to find the fist 002, count the number of processes, and sum the days based on this nmber of processes.